# SpannableStringBuilder not working in some devices

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, spannablestringbuilder

SpannableStringBuilder decorations not working in some devices . I am setting typeface, font color using SpannableStringBuilder in java code and setting in the textview .

Comment: Can you please post your code and the error log ? And why you post the rest of the problem as an answer?

Comment: @Amine 
There were no error log . As I mentioned above only the decorations are not working that too in some devices . There is no error log for that . 
Regarding the code , the don't think there is need for some specific implementation . Any SpannableStringBuilder will work . 

I have posted separate question and answer because the problem is general but the solution is not . They may be other better solutions to it , I just posted the answer which worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because android:textAllCaps="" attribute removes the string decorations done using SpannableStringBuilder in some devices like Moto series.
Remove the android:textAllCaps attribute

Comment: Damnit, I was looking for this kind of answer, I searched a lot by myself and ten minutes ago, I found the problem and indeed it was "textAllCaps"